# Сочетание «пожалуй что» в значении «пожалуй»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Если слово "пожалуй" употребляется вместе с "что", оно теряет статус вводного слова и не отделяется запятыми?

*Пожалуй что в этом году случится Армагеддон.

Я предпочту, пожалуй что, яблок, одну корзинку.*

Answer (score 1):

У Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122 см. п. 8:
"В зависимости от контекста одни и те же слова выступают то в качестве членов предложения, то в роли вводных слов (следовательно, не членов предложения)", и в конце пункта – пример с "пожалуй что".

Comment: Иллюстрацией написанному у Розенталя служит начало знаменитой эпиграммы Виельгорского в переводе Е. Витковского:            
"Спокойно мы вздохнём, пожалуй что, впервой."